# How to activate a window after it has lost focus?

Tags: autohotkey

So i am using this great software called Website-Watcher, which is rss feed reader and web content tracker.

I have configured it to open external links in firefox, which is opening tabs in the background.

BUT the problem is that Website-Watcher looses focus after i hit some link, so is there a way to open a link, regain lost focus and send click to be able to scroll, i have found a script that activates window on mouse scroll BUT the scroll functionality of program is not regained.

Please, give me some ideas!

EDIT UPDATE::: I have finally made it work, the problem was with the Windows 8.1 Admin rights, because i run Website-Watcher elevated, script that i was using stopped working.

The scripts are here:

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/6292-send-mouse-scrolls-to-window-under-mouse/
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/99405-hoverscroll-verticalhorizontal-scroll-without-focus-scrollwheel-acceleration/?p=623967

With those scripts you can perform scroll without activating windows or if you use the former you can even activate windows with mouse scroll.

Answer (score 3):

Use `WinActivate`

For example, `WinActivate Untitled - Notepad` would activate (bring focus to) the window "Untitled - Notepad". This title must be exact and is case-sensitive.

Comment: How would you scroll a window that is not activated? I think i cannot solve the problem of activating, because if i were to activate that window everytime it losses focus, in a loop, it wouldnt be a good idea, what do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure. I once used a dual monitor program that let you scroll windows that were out of focus, but it messed up a lot of things.

If I understand right, you want to have Website-Watcher in focus, but still be able to scroll your Firefox window?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to do this in a low-tech way. I'm not familiar with Website-Watcher, so I'll share a script I use that you should be able to adapt.

I use Feedly in Chrome for RSS reading, and hitting "v" in Feedly opens the story in a new tab. I use my Media Play button to hit "v" and bring me back to Feedly:

```
Media_Play_Pause::
send v
sleep 50
send {Ctrl Down}{Shift Down}{Tab}{Shift Up}{Ctrl Up}
return
```

So, define your hotkey, have it trigger the link to open in Firefox, and then hit Alt-Tab to jump back:

```
X::
send y
sleep 50
send {Alt Down}{Tab}{Alt Up}
return
```

Obviously, replace "X" and "y" above.

I don't care about using my Media Play button for anything else, but if you want your hotkey to be context sensitive, use [#IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).

Comment: Sorry, my english is not that good, maybe i was unclear, the problem is not that firefox jumps and becomes foreground window, but website-watcher looses focus and you have to click on it to regain focus and be able to scroll, that is my primary concern. My reasoning is this:  
1. loose focus
2. regain focus
3 send just one click to restore scroll functionality

Could this be done?

Comment: Once Firefox opens, hit Alt-Tab once. Is Website-Watcher back in focus and scrollable? My guess is "yes."

Answer (score 0):

Use `"WinGet, variableName , List, yourWindowName"` (without quote)

then call your variableName contate it with `1` in every `ControlSend`

for example :

```
WinGet, nexid, List, myHyperTerminal

ControlSend, , {shift down}at=cmgs{shift up}=303{ENTER},  ahk_id %nexid1%
sleep, 1000
ControlSend, , {shift down}sms{shift up}{space}10000,  ahk_id %nexid1%
sleep, 1000
```

if you want to use control key such as shift, ctrl, alt, don't forget to add  `"SetKeyDelay, intDelay, intPressDuration"` (without quote)

for example the script will be list this

```
#usehook on
SetKeyDelay, 50, 20
WinGet, nexid, List, zz1

$F6::

ControlSend, , {shift down}at=cmgs{shift up}=303{ENTER},  ahk_id %nexid1%
sleep, 1000
ControlSend, , {shift down}sms{shift up}{space}10000,  ahk_id %nexid1%
sleep, 1000

return
$F7::pause
```

it will be sent to active/inactive window "zz1" as :

```
AT+CMGS=303
SMS 10000
```